# Why does Tornado Cash can not be attack by "front running attack"?

Tags: contract-development, encryption, zksnark, frontrunning, tornado-cash

If a miner sees the transaction with the "Tornado Cash withdraw" in the mempool and decides to create another transaction of his own,  how the Tornado Cash defeat this?

Comment: The generated proof for withdrawing is valid for a single destination address and relayer.

Answer (score 1):

I was also worried but after reading @user2284570 response, I understand. So if front runner changes to their address, the proof will be invalid.

That is a perfect Block from frontrunners.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).